# Need help with the following type for agrument in function call:

Tags: solidity, remix

TypeError: Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from bytes calldata to uint256 requested.
        proposals.push(msg.data);

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

    contract FantasyLeague {
        // Define addresses of league members
        address public member;
        // Hold data of proposed number
        uint[] public proposals;

        // Deploy contract
        constructor() public {
            member = msg.sender;
        }

        // Propose new team number
        function proposeNumber (uint) public payable {
            require(msg.value > .01 ether);
            proposals.push(msg.data);
        }

        // Retrieve List of current proposals
        function getProposals () public view returns (uint[]) {
            return proposals;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear what you're trying to do, but you probably just want this:

```
function proposeNumber(uint number) public payable {
    require(msg.value > .01 ether);
    proposals.push(number);
}
```

Comment: Thanks smarx!  I now realize I also need to ensure users don't vote with multiple account addresses which can be generated quite easily.  What would be the easiest way to ensure that?  Through a modifier?  Or perhaps through some delegate function?

Comment: I'm unclear on your requirement. Can you define what a "user" is and how it differs from an "account?"

Comment: A user is someone in our league who needs to cast a vote.  If a user is utilizing Meta Mask to cast their vote, can't they produce multiple "addresses" on their Meta Mask account and theoretically have multiple votes by the same person?

Comment: Yes. It's impossible from within a smart contract to know something about the identity of a human. You'd need some external vetting process (like whitelisting one address per human who presents an ID to you in person or something like that).

Answer (score 1):

since  `msg.data` is bytes and here `proposals` is array of `uint256` you need convert `bytes` to `uint`

```
 function proposeNumber () public payable {
           uint temp;
           require(msg.value > .01 ether);
           // bytes calldata is not implicitly convertible to expected type storage pointer so use memory
            bytes memory b = msg.data;
            for(uint i=0;i<b.length;i++){
            temp = temp + uint(b[i])*(2**(8*(b.length-(i+1))));
            }
            proposals.push(temp);
         }
```